# Map LiveData<PagedList<X>> to LiveData<PagedList<Y>>

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I need to map domain objects to UI objects and display using a live paged list.

I have tried to map `LiveData<PagedList<X>>` to `LiveData<PagedList<Y>>`, and map `PositionalDataSource<X>` to `PositionalDataSource<Y>`, but due to package private and private restrictions these both appear to be impossible without placing my code in android.arch.paging package and using reflection, or using a modified version of the paging lib.

Does anyone know of a way to do this without resorting to such undesirable methods?

(Note that this would not be an issue if the paging library API used interfaces instead of abstract base classes - that would allow wrapping any paged list/data source and add appropriate mappings.)

Answer (score 20):

DataSource and DataSource.Factory have `mapBy()` and `mapPageBy()`, which could help you in this case. Just be careful cause these two will restrict the size of the "Y"-result-list.

If the size of the result differs from the original list's size then DataSource will throw an Exception.

Comment: I didn't get how to properly use those functions, as both of them return a DataSource<Key, ToValue> object.
Do you have any example on how to use those functions to properly map LiveData<PagedList<X>> to LiveData<PagedList<Y>> ?

Even better, map PagedList<X> to PagedList<Y>

Comment: @HeitorColangelo, I don't have an example on hand right now.
 But hope this helps: you have a Room DataSource (let's name it Db) which returns a PagedList<X> object . in order to get a PagedList<Y> , you have to create MyDataSource class which will take the Db DataSource and call Db.mapBy() and Db.mapPageBy() in order for MyDataSource to return a LiveData<PagedList<Y>> object.

Comment: thanks, @edy, also I search data source transform got me the same documentation page.

Answer (score 6):

For me following worked :

```
  val dataSourceFactory = 
         cache.getDataSourceFactory(params)
              .map {
                   convertXToY(it)
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Paging 3 library PagingData mapping (RxPagingSource+RxJava2)

```
val pagingData: PagingData<X> = //TODO
pagingData.map { pagingData ->
    pagingData.mapAsync { x ->
        Single.just(Y(x))
    }
}
```