# How to add new items to a pagedList backed by Room?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-paging-library

I am using Network + Database for pagination in my app. I have 2 model classes that extends same types. Only one type of model is backed by a Room database. I want to inject other model class in between the `PagedList` based on some business rules. When I try to do that by using `mapByPage` function on `DataSource.Factory` returned by Room. The paging library is throwing `IllegalStateExeception` with message that size has changed. How do I go about implementing this case?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help us answer your question if you could post a full error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the size of the list needs to be the same. I tried to look for official documentation but I couldn't find it.

But found this comment
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49666673/430652